# Blender to three.js - Materials not appearing correctly when making material not transparent

Tags: three.js, export, rendering, blender, makehuman

I have been trying to make characters in blender and then export it to three.js. However, the materials for the character's eye seems to be broken as it renders a light blue color, instead of being the eye image. This results in very creepy characters.

I am using the normal Blender Renderer, and I created the character with MakeHuman. The export settings are as follows:

- Scene: Scene and Materials
- Geometry: BufferGeometry, Uint16Array, Vertices, Faces, Normals, UVs, Apply Modifiers
- Texture: Textures, Export Textures, Embed Textures

When I import the object, I change "transparent" to false, but I have tried changing a lot of things, and no difference seems to come. All my other objects render completely fine when I do this though.

I have a .blend, .json, and png of the eye [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?1yod46iue5lug)

Some other strange things that I have noticed is that when testing my object on the threejs.org editor, the texture begins to appear slightly after zooming out away from it and even becomes the right texture after reloading the page.

Here is a picture of the "transparancy" area of my eye material. 
[image: eye material transparency]
I noticed that if I toggle it, I get the blue eye effect. I think that might be why I am getting the issue. How do I make the material appear while transparent is set to true?

Comment: Do you have a working fiddle to show? Put your project in http://jsfiddle.net/ so we can see what the problem is, because the problem could be a million different things.

Comment: Ok, [here it is](https://jsfiddle.net/ypxsfq8d/14/). I also just noticed that if the camera gets really close to the model, then the eye just disappears...

Comment: Please give [glTFExporter](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-Exporter) a try. You can load the `glTF` file with [GLTFLoader](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, nothing changed and the eyes still appeared without the texture.

Comment: I recommend you import your textures as JPGs or PNGs and manually assign them to each object's material. Kind of how you did for the grass and brick wall. I'm guessing the eye texture data is getting corrupted in your JSON file.

Comment: I did check the data url of the eye and it seems fine, but i'll give it a try.

Comment: It didn't appear to make a difference, the eye stayed a light blue color.